# Axis labels fixed at origin

Tags: pstricks

I'm trying to graph an implicit function using pstricks and the axis labels always appear at the origin.  My code and output is below, but I've tried other examples online and my output always places the axis labels at the origin, whereas the examples do not show this problem.

I'm using TeXworks 0.6.5 on Arch Linux.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-10,-6)(3,6)
  \psaxes{<->}(0,0)(-10.0,-6.0)(3.0,6.0)[$a$,0][$j \cdot b$,90]
  \psplotImp[
    linecolor=red,
    stepFactor=0.1,
    algebraic,
    ](-10.0,-6.0)(3.0,6.0){x^2 + y^2 + 2*(x - 0.8^2* sqrt(x^2 + y^2)) / (1 - 0.8^2) + 1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Implicit Function]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, unfortunately it did not work.  I did find a solution however and thought I should post it for others that may have the same issue.

The problem is that I'm using XeLaTeX to compile.  Apparently there are some issues in doing it this way that are beyond my understanding.

The solution was to run the following commands below in terminal, taking care to be in the same directory as the files (taking care to substitute  for the actual file name.

```
latex <filename>.tex
dvips <filename>.dvi
ps2pdf <filename>.ps
```

This generated the plot perfectly.